# UITableViewCell not respects constraints depending on the content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I've a Cell to show data of a order. The labels of the order and your contents has different sizes.. But when is too large I wants trunc tail. But this not happens. The size of content modify my View no motivation.

This is my Cell.xib. I've seted carefully the constraints.

[image]

The results: My purple view has resized.

[image]

Comment: you want the purple part to be consistent ?

Comment: Yes, all itens of the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control drag from the purple view to the contentView and select **Equal-Widths** , then modify the multiplier to say 0.2

**Edit:**

Select constraint and

[image]

Comment: where I modify the multiplier?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest set a **width constraint** to the purple view. A better approach would be using stack view to organize your content.

Comment: If I use stack view I can't change the widht-height size

Comment: The Y value, I can't change.

Comment: Just put stackview directly to contentview and set top bottom leading trailing to contentview with constant 0

Comment: I can't do this, my view have margins and round corners, because this I've a View inside ContentView

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase horizontal resistance priority of your purple view. Try more than 750.

Its located just under the constraints menu.

Check this: [ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCwHI.png)